# A method to solve a word search in Java using 2d arrays.?

Tags: java, arrays, search, 2d

I'm trying to create a method that will search through a 2d array of numbers. If the numbers add up to a certain sum, those numbers should remain and all of the other numbers should be changed to a 0. For example, if the desired sum is 7 and a row contains 2 5 1 2, the result should be 2 5 0 0 after the method is implemented. I have everything functioning but instead of keeping all of the numbers that add up to the sum, only the last number is retained. So, I am left with 0 5 0 0 . I think I need another array somewhere but not sure exactly how to go about implementing it. Any ideas?

```
public static int[][] horizontalSums(int[][] a, int sumToFind) {
    int[][] b = new int[a.length][a[0].length];
    int columnStart = 0;
    while (columnStart < a[0].length) {
        for (int row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int column = columnStart; column < a[row].length; column++) {
                sum += a[row][column];
                if (sum == sumToFind) {
                    b[row][column] = a[row][column];
                }
            }

        }
        columnStart++;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example you use 2 5 1 1, would 0 5 1 1 also be a valid response?  Or do you just need to find any combination?  A recursive function may be the best solution.

If you just need to scan through the array and add up the numbers until the sum is reached then just add a for loop to copy the previous values from the array to the new array when the sum is found.  Something like:

```
if (sum == sumToFind) 
{
   for (int i= 0; i<= columnStart; i++)
{
    b[row][i] = a[row][i];
}
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean for 0 5 1 1 to add up to 7 lol. It was my mistake. I changed it to 2 5 1 2. It just needs to be searched once. Not multiple times for multiple combinations.

Comment: Ok then the above should work for that example anyway

Comment: I tried it. It gave me 2 0 0 0. Only the first number that adds up to 7 remained whereas with my code the last number remained.

Comment: You definitely used LESS THAN OR EQUAL in your for loop?  Step through it with breakpoints to make sure the for loop is looping enough times

Comment: I tried to go through it pretty thoroughly. That didn't work among with other things I tried. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can't be far off, just think a bit harder!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sum == sumToFind) 
{
   for (int i= columnStart; i<= column; i++)
{
    b[row][i] = a[row][i];
}
}
```

A minor tweak was all it needed.  If you have columnStart and column like in the other answer, it only finds the first number of the series.